# how to create dynamic two dimensional array in java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I want to create a two dimensional array dynamically.

I know the number of columns. But the number of rows are being changed dynamically. I tried the array list, but it stores the value in single dimension only. What can I do?

Comment: Did you try a list of list? like List<List<Integer>>

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Since the number of columns is a constant, you can just have an `List` of `int[]`.

```
    import java.util.*;
    //...

    List<int[]> rowList = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    rowList.add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
    rowList.add(new int[] { 4, 5, 6 });
    rowList.add(new int[] { 7, 8 });

    for (int[] row : rowList) {
        System.out.println("Row = " + Arrays.toString(row));
    } // prints:
      // Row = [1, 2, 3]
      // Row = [4, 5, 6]
      // Row = [7, 8]

    System.out.println(rowList.get(1)[1]); // prints "5"
```

Since it's backed by a `List`, the number of rows can grow and shrink dynamically. Each row is backed by an `int[]`, which is static, but you said that the number of columns is fixed, so this is not a problem.

Comment: what changes should be made to implement an arrayList with fixed rows but variable columns?

Comment: What kind of answer is this..? If we wanted to define anything constant, we could simple use an array... Does Java have a C++ equivalent vector class where you can dynamically add rows & columns (without having to write your own..)?

Answer (score 20):

There are no multi-dimensional arrays in Java, there are, however, arrays of arrays.

Just make an array of however large you want, then for each element make another array however large you want that one to be.

```
int array[][];

array = new int[10][];

array[0] = new int[9];
array[1] = new int[8];
array[2] = new int[7];
array[3] = new int[6];
array[4] = new int[5];
array[5] = new int[4];
array[6] = new int[3];
array[7] = new int[2];
array[8] = new int[1];
array[9] = new int[0];
```

Alternatively:

```
List<Integer>[] array;

array = new List<Integer>[10];

// of you can do "new ArrayList<Integer>(the desired size);" for all of the following
array[0] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
array[1] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
array[2] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
array[3] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
array[4] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
array[5] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
array[6] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
array[7] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
array[8] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
array[9] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: Should be accepted as it shows the actual way without - and with - the arraylist.

Answer (score 2):

One more example for 2 dimension String array:

```
public void arrayExam() {
    List<String[]> A = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    A.add(new String[] {"Jack","good"});
    A.add(new String[] {"Mary","better"});
    A.add(new String[] {"Kate","best"});
    for (String[] row : A) {
        Log.i(TAG,row[0] + "->" + row[1]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
17467 08-02 19:24:40.518  8456  8456 I MyExam  : Jack->good
17468 08-02 19:24:40.518  8456  8456 I MyExam  : Mary->better
17469 08-02 19:24:40.518  8456  8456 I MyExam  : Kate->best
```

Answer (score 1):

How about making a custom class containing an array, and use the array of your custom class.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make `Treemap < Integer, Treemap<Integer, obj> >`

In java, Treemap is sorted map. And the number of item in row and col wont screw the 2D-index you want to set.
Then you can get a col-row table like structure.

Comment: A nice generic way for implementing a sizable 2D array in Java. You must use Integer, though, as primitives cannot be keys of Treemap.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example.
this method will return a 2 dimensional `tType` array

```
public tType[][] allocate(Class<tType> c,int row,int column){
        tType [][] matrix = (tType[][]) Array.newInstance(c,row);
        for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {
            matrix[i] = (tType[]) Array.newInstance(c,column);
        }
        return matrix;

    }
```

say you want a 2 dimensional String array, then call this function as

```
String [][] stringArray = allocate(String.class,3,3);
```

This will give you a two dimensional String array with 3 rows and 3 columns;
Note that in `Class<tType> c` -> `c` cannot be primitive type like say, `int` or `char` or `double`. It must be non-primitive like, `String` or `Double` or `Integer` and so on.

Comment: This code does not compile for me, I get a compilation error on "tType". Can you give the full code please?

Answer (score 0):

simple you want to inialize a 2d array and assign a size of array then 
a example is

```
   public static void main(String args[])
   { 
    char arr[][];   //arr is 2d array name
    arr = new char[3][3]; 
    }


   //this is a way to inialize a 2d array in java....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in) ;
int p[][] = new int[n][] ;
for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
{
    int m = sc.nextInt() ;      //Taking input from user in JAVA.
    p[i]=new int[m] ;       //Allocating memory block of 'm' int size block.

    for(int j=0 ; j<m ; j++)
    {
         p[i][j]=sc.nextInt();   //Initializing 2D array block.
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please add a bit of explanation - a bare code block isn't all that informative.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer>[] array;  
array = new List<Integer>[10];
```

this the second case in @TofuBeer's answer is incorrect. because **can't create arrays with generics**. u can use:

```
List<List<Integer>> array = new ArrayList<>();
```