# Writing two dimensional array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following two dimensional array in my java program.

```
Integer[][] arrayOfSets = {
        {1,2,5,6,9,10},
        {9,10,11,12},
        {1,2,3,4},
        {3,5,6,7,8},
        {9,10,11,12},
        {4,8},
};
```

Can someone show me the code on how to make the program dynamic, where the program asks the user to enter the row number and column number, i.e. how many arrays the two dimensional array should hold and then asks the user for how big each array and what are the numbers that each array should hold?
Thanks so much in advance.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
 System.out.println("HOw many sets arrays would you like");
    int numArrays=sc.nextInt();
    Integer [][] arrayName = new Integer[numArrays][];
    for(int i=0;i<arrayName.length;i++){
        System.out.println("enter the size of the array number"+i);
        int sizeArray=sc.nextInt();
        for(int k=0;k<sizeArray;k++){
            System.out.println("enter element");
            int e=sc.nextInt();
            arrayName[i][k]=e;
        }

    }
```

Does this look right? Thanks for all the help in advance.

Ok I modified my cod again. Following is what I have now:

System.out.print("How many arrays would you like?");
    int numSets=sc.nextInt();
    Integer[][] result = new Integer[numSets][];

```
for (int k=0; k< numSets; k++){
  System.out.println("Enter the size of the array");
  int setSize  = sc.nextInt();

  Integer[] row = new Integer[setSize];
  for (int m=0; m< setSize; m++){
      System.out.println("enter element: ");
      row[m] = sc.nextInt();
  }
  result[k] = row;
}
```

Comment: Please see my code and let me know if that's correct. Thanks.

Comment: An observation: Java does not support true multi-dimensional arrays; rather, it supports 1-dimensional arrays, where each element can itself be another 1-dimensional array. The difference is the way memory is allocated, where `a[i][j]` differs from `a[i,j]`.

Comment: `Does this look right?` I don't know, what errors are you getting?

Comment: Already posted on SO.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707357/how-to-create-dynamic-two-dimensional-array-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just prompt the user for the initial array sizes then initialize the array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class blah {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How Many Rows?");
        int rows = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How Many Colums?");
        int cols = s.nextInt();
        int [][] arrayOfSets = new int [rows] [cols];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you have is almost correct. This:

```
Integer [][] arrayName = new Integer[numArrays][];
```

creates the first dimension, but you also need to create the individual second dimensions. After you read in the size of the each array:

```
int sizeArray=sc.nextInt();
```

you need to create the corresponding array:

```
arrayName[i] = new Integer[sizeArray];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample function you could adapt:

```
 Integer[][] createSampleArray()
 {
      final int N1 = 5;
      Random r = new Random();
      Integer[][] result = new Integer[N1][];
      for (int i = 0; i < N1; ++i)
      {
          final int N2 = r.nextInt();
          Integer[] row = new Integer[N2];
          for (int j = 0; j < N2; ++j)
          {
              row[j] = r.nextInt();
          }
          result[i] = row;
      }
      return result;
 }
```

---

Aha, your problem is you're not creating any 1-D arrays to put the elements in:

```
Integer [][] arrayName = new Integer[numArrays][];
    for(int i=0;i<arrayName.length;i++){
        System.out.println("enter the size of the array number"+i);
        int sizeArray=sc.nextInt();
        for(int k=0;k<sizeArray;k++){
            System.out.println("enter element");
            int e=sc.nextInt();
            arrayName[i][k]=e;
        }

    }
```

You can't assign `arrayName[i][k]` until you assign `arrayName[i]` first for each row:

`arrayName[i] = new Integer[sizeArray]`;

Comment: @user491753: the customary response when you like an answer is to upvote it and/or accept....

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. I keep on asking people to tell me how to do that but no one answers....

Comment: they're on the upper left corner of any of the answers: there's a vote count with an up arrow above it, and a down arrow below it, and you should also see an outline of a checkbox. click on the appropriate one to activate.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this SOq:

- [how to create dynamic two dimensional array in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707357/how-to-create-dynamic-two-dimensional-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

@casablanca answer is perfect. You need to create the object of 'Integer' class in the end

```
 for(int j=0; j < arrayname[i].length; j++)
  arrayname[i][j] = new Integer(int_value);
```