# Dynamic two dimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

How can create a dynamic two dimensional array in Java, and how can I get and set its elements and go through all elements?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707357/how-to-create-dynamic-two-dimensional-array-in-java) post. But in the post one of the dimensions (number of rows) is known and fixed but in my case both are variable.

Comment: What about List<List<Object>> then? i.e. a List of Lists

Comment: Why don't you use List of List's ? Rather than trying to change the number of rows and columns dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible, arrays are always static in length.

Try using a list of lists.

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> list = new LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>();

list.add(new LinkedList<String>()); // [[]]
list.get(0).add("hello"); // [["hello"]]
list.get(0).add("world"); // [["hello", "world"]]

list.add(new LinkedList<String>()); // [["hello", "world"], []]
list.get(1).add("bonjour"); // [["hello", "world"], ["bonjour"]]
```

The list can use any class instead of String.

To loop through the lists, you'd need to do something like the following:

```
for(LinkedList<String> subList : list){
    for(String str : subList){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks how can I go through all elements, using the for loop and iterator?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use List or ArrayList it allows for 2 dimensional arrays with different data types and you can add/remove rows as needed.

see [2 dimensional array list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866205/2-dimensional-array-list)

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
tempList.add("one");
tempList.add("two");

listOfLists.add(tempList);
```

Any data structure with similar functionality will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have answered, we cannot have arrays with dynamic lengths in Java. To get around this, you can something like `java.util.ArrayList`. We can keep adding entities to an `ArrayList` without needing to give a final size of that List.

Classes like `ArrayList` are able to do this, because they keep creating new arrays within themselves to store data. An `ArrayList<String>` initially will create a `String[]` array of size 10 (that's an example size), but when you add an 11th element to the ArrayList, it will create a new String[] of size 20 (again, thats an example size) and copy contents of Old Array in to New Array.

In order to create new Arrays in a fast manner, it uses this Method: `System.arrayCopy(Object src,  int  srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)`

So you could technically do the same thing. Every time you need an array of larger size:

- Create New Array of somewhat larger size
- Copy contents of Old into New
- Discard Old Array

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for a two-dimensional ArrayList of Strings:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Matrix {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> matrix;

    Matrix () {
        matrix = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    void set(int i, int j, String value) {
        while (matrix.size() <= i) {
            matrix.add(new ArrayList<String>());
        }
        while (matrix.get(i).size() <= j) {
            matrix.get(i).add("");
        }
        matrix.get(i).set(j, value);
    }

    String get(int i, int j) {
        try {
            return matrix.get(i).get(j);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            return "";
        }
    }

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getMatrix() {
        return matrix;
    }
}
```

Here's how to fill the array and go through the elements:

```
Matrix matrix;
matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.set(3, 5, "You");
matrix.set(0, 0, "Hi");

for (ArrayList<String> list : matrix.getMatrix()) {
    for (String value : list) {
        System.out.print(value + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use an `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` but if you insist on using an `array` then what you could do is check if the array of size `n x m` is full before assigning a value. If it is full then you create a new multidimensional array of size `(n+1) x (m+1)` and copy all the values over using a loop.

This method is not preferable because it uses a lot more resources since you need to re-create and copy the array every time it gets full.